# Problems on group action.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, problem-solving, group-actions

I am a graduate student of Mathematics. In our algebra course, I recently learnt group actions.

I want some nice problems on group actions so that I have a firm grasp of the subject after doing those exercises.

I have referred to many books but the problems there are not much interesting. I want some concept-based problems on group actions.

I tried to find it on stackexchange but searching among so many problems is difficult.

So, can someone suggest to me some stackexchange pages or some exercises on group action that will help me to understand the concepts?

Comment: Dummit and Foote have a good set of exercises in *"Abstract Algebra (Third Edition)"*

Comment: You could have a look at the book which you can find as pdf im Google with the title, GEOMETRY OF SURFACES of John Stillwell on chapter 2. There, you will see the group action of isometries of the real plane acting on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think considering the action of ${\rm SL}_2\Bbb R$ on the upper half-plane by Mobius transformations is very instructive. Find the stabilizer of $i$ and that stabilizer's orbits. Show the action is sharply $3$-transitive. Show the upper triangular matrices are a regular subgroup. In general, you can show any group is a knit product of a stabilizer and a regular subgroup.

Comment: Also good exercises: Burnside's lemma for counting beaded necklaces, showing the categorical version of the orbit-stabilizer theorem (that any orbit is equivalent to the coset space of the stabilizer), which classifies transitive actions. You can show that $2$-transitive implies primitive but not conversely, and actions are primitive iff stabilizers are maximal subgroups. Show the rotational symmetry group of a cube is $S_4$ using space diagonals, and show there are homos $S_4\to S_3$ and $S_4\to S_2$ using induced actions on axes and inscribed tetrahedra. These are off the top of my head.